# Motivating Examples for Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the first semester of algebraic topology, you generally learn about the fundamental group and homology, both of which are reasonably geometric. There are also many motivating examples, like $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(S^n) = \mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 1$, which illustrate what $\pi_1$ and $H_n$ are detecting. The second semester is usually spent on cohomology, where examples are sparser and the focus seems to be developing algebraic machinery. I found myself performing many computations with no physical intuition, which is fine for an algebra course but not what I would expect from a topology course.

In light of this, what are the best topological examples of how cohomology (and all the machinery behind it) could be motivated? I would prefer examples to help build intuition, but historical examples and useful applications are welcome.

Comment: What don't you find geometric or intuitive about cohomology? Poincare duality is a pretty solid link between them, but de Rham cohomology is at least completely geometric (and the extra ring operation in cohomology corresponds nicely to the wedge product of forms).

Comment: For me, the motiviation for all these "classification of topological spaces" are always "How many shapes of spacetimes/surfaces are there"? A big part of understanding gauge theory is e.g. understanding "all possible 4-dimensional manifolds" (which we by the way dont).

Answer (score 2):

The group $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ is the amalgamated free product
$$ 
SL_2(\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z/4\ast_{\Bbb Z/2}\Bbb Z/6.
$$
This has a nice background and motivation from algebraic topology. Applying the long *Mayer-Vietoris sequence* we can compute the cohomology with trivial coefficients as follows:
$$
H^k(SL_2(\Bbb Z))=\begin{cases} \Bbb Z & \text{ for } k=0,\\
0   & \text{ for $k$ odd,} \\
\Bbb Z/12   & \text{ for $k>0$ even.} 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I like this example, but it probably bears mentioning for the OP that $H^*(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ is the group cohomology of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (acting trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$), not the singular, etc. cohomology of the discrete topological space $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.